# How to watch for UNHANDLED exceptions only using WaitForDebugEvent family functions?

Tags: windows, debugging, crash

I'm trying to catch unhandled exceptions in the application and restart it on them using WaitForDebugEvent function. But I can't tell when exception is handled by application (try..catch for example) and when is not. How do I do that? There seem to be no such data in DEBUG_EVENT structure.

Comment: What operating system?  Are you writing a debugger or trying to use a debugger?

Comment: I'm writting a software, that will act as a debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your not catching certain exceptions using `WaitForDebugEvent`, you might want to try injecting an `UnhandledExceptionFilter` as well. other than that, check that your processing matches [Microsofts Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681675%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, but crashing software is not mine. So, I can't handle any exceptions there.

Comment: Yes you can, ollydbg does this(injecting an exception filter into the target process) to process exceptions, you can just subclass the processes filter

Answer (score 1):

In the `EXCEPTION_DEBUG_INFO` structure, which is in the `DEBUG_EVENT` structure, there is a field dwFirstChance:

> If the dwFirstChance member is nonzero, this is the first time the debugger has encountered the exception. Debuggers typically handle breakpoint and single-step exceptions when they are first encountered. If this member is zero, the debugger has previously encountered the exception. This occurs only if, during the search for structured exception handlers, either no handler was found or the exception was continued.

So you will want to look for times where dwFirstChance is 0.

But if you just want to restart your app when it fails, it might be easier to create another app to watch for the failure of the first one, rather than using the Windows debugging api.

Comment: For some reason it's always 1 in my application.

Comment: There is a trouble with just watching, because Windows don't stop your process on crash. It shows nice UI reporting the problem and until that crashed process is still in memory.